# Is it not unsafe for a laptop to hibernate/suspend while an SD card is mounted?

Tags: power, laptop

I have been witnessing for years my Dell laptop freezes as it resumes from hibernating while an SD card is inserted in the slot and mounted. It of course took me some time to figure that out, but I can reproduce the incident with 100% accuracy now: *every time* my laptop resumes from hibernating — as I programmed the power manager to when the remaining time goes beyond 8% — while there is an SD card inserted and mounted it freezes (locks up), and I can only hard power it down... losing of course more than a few nibbles from my SD card every time. I can lose up to hundreds of megabytes in one go.

Recently I happened to power a computer with a 12 V battery. At some time I saw it completely freeze while it was running from my USB key, which I had setup as a boot device [to run Linux Mint]. I later realized the computer had frozen, because I had forgotten to plug the power charger and the battery voltage had decreased to something like 11.5 volts. I also discovered the USB key partition I was using to boot the computer with had been completely corrupt and non-recoverable in the process.

Add to it that I also read many times [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) users (like me) have reported SD card corruption and the latter are [due to (low) power issues](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=36533). This explanation came to me as I (also) noticed the usable size of my Raspberry Pi SD card significantly decreased for unknown reasons before I read that.

### Conclusion

So in short I've been taught the hard way the lethal consequences of running on fumes with flash devices while they're being used.

---

I am only suspecting it's an electrical issue, so I'm basically asking for confirmation. I have experienced a couple of issues in the past with SD card drivers which made (at least) Linux suffer from a variety of bugs, including system freezes, especially when those drivers were young, i.e. not as mature as today. With time I have come to wonder if my laptop freezes (under the conditions mentioned above) could be due to how the hardware reacts when battery power is getting somewhat «low».

**My question is**: *Does my analysis make some sense or is it really something else, like poor power management design on certain laptops, whatever?*

If it is correct, then should it not be recommended for to laptop users to plug the mains when using an SD card? (Regardless of the fact it's always [best to run on mains as much as possible](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39396#39403).)

---

*Note: I'm asking the question here for I suspect what I've been thinking is a bug in Linux SD card driver actually is an electronics (engineering) issue.*

Comment: @tcrosley I tend to disagree as it first needs to be confirmed the issues reported in the question are irrelevant of the electronics hardware, don't you think? That's the reason I asked for some expertise here.

Comment: Superuser site can help with that better than here IMO.  They have plenty of questions already concerning SD card problems -- just do a search over there for "SD card".

Comment: Well, I did but found nothing relevant enough to my taste. But maybe I'm too picky, dunno.

Comment: The raspi is atypically fragile, and notorious for these issues. I suspect it comes from using a sd card as *root* and the wierd nature of the raspi boot process.

Comment: Does the SDcard reader on your Dell use a MMC interface (i.e. /dev/mmcblk<x>) or connect through the disk interface (/dev/sd<x>)?

Comment: @sawdust It has a MMC interface indeed.

Answer (score 1):

*Warning: no Linux expert here*.

The card corruption could be due to the hibernation process not disconnecting the card correctly or not waiting enough for the card to complete a write cycle with data possibly still in the PC cache. Hardware damages to flash memory cards are much more common when something bad (e.g. power failure) happens during write operations.

As for the PC freezing I suspect some OS component has some issues. Probably some driver is not robust enough to handle hardware failure during the hibernation process. If some non-essential hardware component (like the SD card reader) fails the OS shouldn't simply freeze or blow-up (that's one of the role of an OS). Admittedly the hibernation process is not a common scenario, so maybe whoever wrote the driver handled exceptional events in the shutdown process (the most common "special" scenario), but forgot or neglected the hibernation process.

P.S.: I've seen also many *Windows* PCs freezing during wake-up from the hibernation or during hibernation, so that I usually disable the feature by default on my Windows machines (standby, on the contrary, works incredibly well most of the time). I suspect interactions with the hardware during hibernation is not a major concern for PC industry.

Comment: Well, I also share your user experience with standby (Sleep, under Linux). Never had a glitch with sleep but I think it's normal as the hardware is still powered on, not with Hibernate.

Comment: @Nasha in reality it's not so simple: even during standby most of the hardware is turned off or put into some low-power state. For example the WiFi transmitter stage is most probably completely shut off, otherwise it will suck out the hell from the battery of a laptop in standby. So, technically, I don't think it is inherently more challenging to deal with hibernation. I suspect it is a neglected feature just because users don't use it too often.

Comment: I get that. So it means I could just be running out of luck in this case, right?

Comment: For the freeze I would report the issue to the developers of your Linux distribution, giving them all the details. Maybe you are lucky and they troubleshoot the thing. Linux devs are usually more prompt to such issues than big corps like MS or Apple.

Comment: Well, reporting is also not as simple as I think I know the answer: does the problem occur with a recent kernel. Mine is that shipped with Linux Mint 16, which I cannot upgrade other than reinstalling everything. And if I'm to upgrade, I only will upgrade to a rolling release, which also has an impact on what packages I'll be able to use. Means: will take a lot of time until I'm clear.

Answer (score 0):

Which filesystem do you use on the sdcard? I suppose that it is fat32 or alike. I think the problem is with some delayed transaction waiting to be made by the sdcard itself, being transparent to the OS. (reported as if it is done to the OS by the sdcard) That transaction goes crazy by a power down slow enough. (I mean the trasient of power down may not be necessarily fast, that makes it prone to being out of defined states. This is probably somehow committed upon the hibernate request, but as hardware delay is being transparent to the filesystem, it won't temporarily block the power-down. My guess is, if you use ext4 or btrfs with barrier option is on (it is by default already) there is a chance it will wait until getting to a safe state.

Is it possible to recover the kernel messages of this event?

---

I tried to replicate the problem with a Dell Studio 14 laptop, archlinux (3.18 vanilla kernel) running on a usb flashdisk, also mounted a 2gb ext2 partition of a sd-card. Suspended to ram with "systemctl suspend". Waked up succesfully.

The suspending is not a straightforward process by just telling the kernel to suspend, that is only the last thing of the suspending script to do. The preperation process may differ on different suspending scripts. For some more information: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate

Comment: SD cards I use mostly were formatted with ext2 or ext3, some with FAT, which I use only casually. And, alas, no, there was never a way to recover the kernel logs after the freeze.

Comment: @nasha, read the new part.